# "They are more convenient and reliable." vs "They are more convenient, and reliable."

Tags: adjectives, commas, comparative

> They are more convenient and reliable.
>
> They are more convenient, and reliable.  <--- *[I'm not sure that this sentence is natural.]*

Am I right that in the first sentence the adjective is "more reliable", but in the second one the adjective is just "reliable"? If my interpretation isn't right, is it possible to write "more reliable" without writing "They are more ... and more ..."?

Comment: You are exactly right. That's why, if you want to avoid confusion in speaking, you might flip the order: "They're reliable, and more convenient." Or: "They're more convenient, and they're also reliable." If you want "more" to apply to both, and you want there to be absolutely no question about the matter, you might say "more" twice.

Comment: What cruthers said, and to add that your first sentence is the best way to apply "more" to both adjectives.